# symfony assertions raw data validation with if/else statement

Tags: php, symfony

I have a such json:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"some name",
   "decorations":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "options":[
            {
               "type":"color",
               "label":"Color",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "label":"Green shades",
                     "color_group":{
                        "shade":"green",
                        "name":"Green"
                     },
                     "colors":[
                        {
                           "rgb":"249,249,249",
                           "hex":"#FBFBFB"
                        },
                        {
                           "rgb":"249,249,250",
                           "hex":"#FBFBFF"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "label":"White shades",
                     "color_group":{
                        "shade":"white",
                        "name":"White"
                     },
                     "colors":[
                        {
                           "rgb":"255,255,255",
                           "hex":"#FFFFFF"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"position",
               "label":"Position",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "label":"Front"
                  },
                  {
                     "label":"Back"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

which I want to validate, rules are:

- `id`, `name`, `decorators` required

  - each decorator should have `id` and `options`

    - each option  should have `type`, `label` and `items`. each option has few types, all of them has same structure of each item except of a `color` type

      - so each item should have `label`, and in case of `color` option each item should have `color_group`, `colors`
        - where `color_group` should have 'shade' and `name`
        - each color in `colors` should have `rgb` and `hex`

I want to use symfony assertions to validate that json, and all is more or less straightforward except that rule where depends on a `type` I have different rules... I do not know how to do it right, I found that I can use expression or callback assertion but in both case it showing how to validate object but not a array.

Here is what I have:

```
        new Assert\Collection(
           [
               'allowExtraFields' => true,
               'fields' => [
                   'id' => [
                       new Assert\Required(),
                       new Assert\Type(['type' => 'integer']),
                   ],
                   'decorations' => new Assert\All(
                       [
                           new Assert\Collection(
                               [
                                   'allowExtraFields' => true,
                                   'fields' => [
                                       'id' => [
                                           new Assert\Required(),
                                           new Assert\Type(['type' => 'integer']),
                                       ],
                                       'options' => new Assert\All(
                                           [
                                               'type' => [
                                                   new Assert\Required(),
                                                   new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                                               ],
                                               'label' => [
                                                   new Assert\Required(),
                                                   new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                                               ],
                                               'items' => new Assert\All(
                                                   [
                                                       new Assert\Collection(
                                                           [
                                                               'allowExtraFields' => true,
                                                               'fields' => [
                                                                   // label is required for all types
                                                                   'label' =>  [
                                                                       new Assert\Required(),
                                                                       new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                                                                   ]
                                                                   // here I should add constraints for colors, if type equal to "color", but do not know how to make that if/else statement...
                                                               ]
                                                           ]
                                                       )
                                                   ]
                                               )
                                           ]
                                       )
                                   ]
                               ]
                           )
                       ]
                   )
               ]
           ]
       );
```

Comment: I can use `AtLeastOneOf` constraint but in that case it'll not check rules depends on  type

Comment: Maybe you can achieve that with `Assert\Expression` but that will be a big expression and I fear it will not be elegant.  You could also create your own validation constraint. By the way how do you send your json to the validator ?

Comment: I'm converting it to the array, with `json_decode`, so simply speaking I'm validating php array